# SQL How to calculate Average time between Order Purchases? (do sql calculations based on next and previous row)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a simple table that contains the customer email, their order count (so if this is their 1st order, 3rd, 5th, etc), the date that order was created, the value of that order, and the total order count for that customer.

Here is what my table looks like

```
Email          Order Date     Value Total
r2n1w@gmail.com 1   12/1/2016   85  5
r2n1w@gmail.com 2   2/6/2017    125 5
r2n1w@gmail.com 3   2/17/2017   75  5
r2n1w@gmail.com 4   3/2/2017    65  5
r2n1w@gmail.com 5   3/20/2017   130 5
ation@gmail.com 1   2/12/2018   150 1
ylove@gmail.com 1   6/15/2018   36  3
ylove@gmail.com 2   7/16/2018   41  3
ylove@gmail.com 3   1/21/2019   140 3
keria@gmail.com 1   8/10/2018   54  2
keria@gmail.com 2   11/16/2018  65  2
```

What I want to do is calculate the time  average between purchase for each customer. So lets take customer ylove. First purchase is on 6/15/18. Next one is 7/16/18, so thats 31 days, and next purchase is on 1/21/2019, so that is 189 days. Average purchase time between orders would be 110 days.

But I have no idea how to make SQL look at the next row and calculate based on that, but then restart when it reaches a new customer.

Here is my query to get that table:

```
SELECT 
F.CustomerEmail
,F.OrderCountBase
,F.Date_Created
,F.Total
,F.TotalOrdersBase
FROM #FullBase F 
ORDER BY f.CustomerEmail
```

If anyone can give me some suggestions, that would be greatly appreciated.

And then maybe I can calculate value differences (in percentage). So for example, ylove spent $36 on their first order, $41 on their second which is a 13% increase. Then their second order was $140 which is a 341% increase. So on average, this customer increased their purchase order value by 177%. Unrelated to SQL, but is this the correct way of calculating a metric like this?

Comment: use lag() analytic function

Comment: Search for "window functions", this feature enables You to use previous or next row along with the current row.

Comment: @Natan . . . Do you care about the time since the last order?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you explain what you mean? Isn't that what I am calculating? Time between 1st and second, second and third, and then average of all that.

Comment: @Natan . . . You are asking about the time between orders, but what about the time since the last order.

Answer (score 3):

looking to your sample you clould try using the diff form min and max date divided  by total

```
select email, datediff(day,  min(Order_Date), max(Order_Date))/(total-1) as avg_days
from your_table  
group by  email
```

and for manage also the one order  only

```
select email, 
  case when  total-1 > 0 then  
    datediff(day,  min(Order_Date), max(Order_Date))/(total-1) 
  else  datediff(day,  min(Order_Date), max(Order_Date)) end as avg_days
from your_table  
group by  email
```

Comment: clever,. but you dont need group by total

Comment: but If you have 2 orders the formula should be (Max  - Min) / (total - 1)  ?

Comment: also for 3  is total -1 @JuanCarlosOropeza  thanks  .. upvoted somewhere

Comment: Now dont know how handle `ation@gmail.com` with only 1 order

Comment: answer  updated . for one order too ...  a case when  for total-1

Answer (score 1):

The simplest formulation is:

```
select email,
       datediff(day,  min(Order_Date), max(Order_Date)) / nullif(total-1, 0) as avg_days
from t  
group by email;
```

You can see this is the case.  Consider three orders with od1, od2, and od3 as the order dates.  The average is:

```
( (od2 - od1) + (od3 - od2) ) / 2
```

Check the arithmetic:

```
--> ( od2 - od1 + od3 - od2 ) / 2
--> ( od3 - od1 ) / 2
```

This pretty obviously generalizes to more orders.

Hence the `max()` minus `min()`.